# Settings Crash when trying to add Google Account

Tags: freeze, crash, settings, google

On Ubuntu 20.04Lts i can't add a Google Account in the settings. It always freezes when trying to log in after I type in my password and give Ubuntu access to my google account.
I hope someone can help me and thanks in advance!

Comment: try resetting your router. i found the solution somewhere else and it worked for me. cheers!

Comment: Also in Ubuntu 22.04 (Gnome 42.2) "gnome-control-center/add account" when adding Google account produces following error:

> $ gnome-control-center 
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
(WebKitWebProcess:2): Gdk-ERROR **: 19:52:09.357: The program 'WebKitWebProcess' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)'.
  (Details: serial 200 error_code 2 request_code 151 (GLX) minor_code 34)

Comment: I am having same issue. Cannot add my Google account. When I go to Settings -> Online Accounts -> Google, a popup appears but 2-3s later entire Settings closes on it's own.